# Save as PDF using Selenium and Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to Save as pdf using the print dialog, a web page where I have already logged on using Selenium and Headless Chrome (v81). All the articles state I should be able to print/save the document as pdf using kiosk mode where the print to pdf happens automatically so the preview dialog is surpressed e.g.

[I cannot get Chrome to default to saving as a PDF when using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801768/i-cannot-get-chrome-to-default-to-saving-as-a-pdf-when-using-selenium)
[Selenium Chrome save as pdf change download folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54578876/selenium-chrome-save-as-pdf-change-download-folder)

So far I have the following code:

```cs
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-extensions", "--test-type", "--allow-insecure-localhost", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--disable-gpu", "--kiosk-printing", "--allow-running-insecure-content"); 
chromeOptions.AcceptInsecureCertificates = acceptInsecureCertificates;
chromeOptions.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Ignore;
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("print.always_print_silent", true);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\Temp");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("savefile.default_directory", @"C:\Temp");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("printing.default_destination_selection_rules", "{\"kind\": \"local\", \"namePattern\": \"Save as PDF\"}");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState", "{\"recentDestinations\": [{\"id\": \"Save as PDF\", \"origin\": \"local\", \"account\": \"\" }],\"version\":2,\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false,\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\"}");                    
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeoutMinutes));
```

Then I print the page using this:

```cs
var driver = FeatureContext.Current.GetWebDriver();
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.print();");
```

But I get the print preview dialog, always and my default printer is set and not Save as PDF.

I would use the chrome command line however for the fact I need to be logged on to the site. What is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 3):

**Update 20/05/2022** : With Selenium 4, now is possible "Save to PDF" more easly. With one condition : Your application needs to run in *headless mode* if not, the Selenium will throw a exception `PrintToPDF is only supported in headless mode`. But If some reason, you *cant* run in headless mode, my previous reply still working.

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.IO;

private static ChromeOptions _chromeOptions;
private static WebDriver _driver;
private static string fileName = "MyPrint";
private static string printFinalPath = Path.Combine($@"C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\Downloads", string.Concat(fileName, ".pdf"));

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     _chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
     _chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless"); //your chrome driver needs run in headless!

     //creating webdriver
     _driver = new ChromeDriver(_chromeOptions);

     //go to the website
     _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

     //defining configurations for de printing
     PrintOptions printOptions = new PrintOptions
     {
          Orientation = PrintOrientation.Portrait
     };

     //printing...
     PrintDocument printDocument = _driver.Print(printOptions);

     //saving the file
     printDocument.SaveAsFile(printFinalPath);
}
```

**Original reply**
Selenium 4, has some new features like, "[Executing Command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64533554/13156642)" via ChromeDevTools. With this feature, we can call something like "PdfAsync" directly from chrome (like [Puppersharp](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/index.html#generate-pdf-files), but using selenium). But unfortunately, we don't have this option enable yet in c#. '[Print-pdf](https://superuser.com/a/1211603)' will be more easy in the future.

However, using selenium 3.141.0, doing some searching in topics from web, I solved this problem with help of your code. I have some problems to convert strings C# to json object.

Use [Logging](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging) in chrome, to help.

**Update 27/07/2021** : Unfortunately, using argument "headless" the "window.print()" will not work.

My final code is :

```cs
public class Program
...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     private static IWebDriver _driver;
     private static ChromeOptions _chromeOptions;
     private static ChromeDriverService _chromeService;
     private static string pathLogChromeDriver = "chrome_driver_logs";
     private static string nameFileLog = "chromedriver.log";

     //creating chrome service, to logging
     _chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(".");

     //using to see the modifications in google chrome arguments
     _chromeService.LogPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), pathLogChromeDriver, nameFileLog); 
     _chromeService.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

     //creating chromeOptions, to set the profile preferences
     _chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

     //using Dictionary to pass parameter name (string) and json object to AddUserProfilePreference.
     Dictionary<string, object> prefs  = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     prefs.Add("downloadFile", "{\"recentDestinations\": [{\"id\": \"Save as PDF\", \"origin\": \"local\", \"account\": \"\" }],\"version\":2,\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false,\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\"}");
     prefs.Add("pathFinalFile", "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Downloads\\");

     //using the dictionary values to set the parameters
     _chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState", prefs["downloadFile"])
     _chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("savefile.default_directory", prefs["pathFinalFile"]); 

     //disable 'chrome is being controlled by automated test software' bar
     _chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("useAutomationExtension", false);
     _chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");

     //using --kiosk-printing to enable "silent printing"
     _chromeOptions.AddArgument("--kiosk-printing");

     //creating webdriver
     _driver = new ChromeDriver(_chromeService, _chromeOptions);
     _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://applitools.com/blog/selenium-4-chrome-devtools/");
     _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

     //run javascript to print
     _driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.print();");

     //is done!
}
```

If window "Save As" still open, some argument is incorrect.